# Where is the code generated by @Compose located in an android project folder structure?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

i'm studying jatpack Compose and trying to read some source code of it. Noticed the Compose annotation is critical in this framework so i want to read the code generated by it to check what is actually done within it. However i cant find where the code locate, and since it's a quit new stuff, nothing could be found through out the internet. Beg for your idea, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

That is a big topic.

The @Composable annotation is not processed by an Annotation Processor that generates source code. Instead Google had built a Kotlin Compiler Plugin that processes the annotation and weaves its magic into the compiled code directly.

Leland Richardson is the engineer that works on this and has explained a lot of what happens behind the curtains. For example, start here:

http://intelligiblebabble.com/compose-from-first-principles/

Comment: Thanks! Very inspiring article for me to get more closer to the source code of Compose! And if there are more articles to introduce some components of Compose like Composer, Composition and so on, that'll help me greatly since i'm searching them eagerly but found nothing.